# Presto installation error

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, presto

Im trying to install presto on a cluster, but when im trying to deploy/ install presto server through the several nodes it gives an error on every node:

> Fatal error: [host1] Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: host1), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode.

Does anyone know where the problem came from?

Comment: I'd guess the error doesn't come from Presto. How do you install it?

Answer (score 0):

That error comes when you don't have SSH connectivity between the node running presto-admin and the nodes in the cluster. The default user for the connection is root, but that can be changed by modifying config.json. Either set up passwordless SSH or specify the SSH password via --password (or -I for an interactive prompt). See the docs for more on this: https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/current/presto-admin/ssh-configuration.html.